# How can I inform eclipse.org that their captcha doesn't work properly?

Tags: eclipse, captcha

I'm trying to reset my eclipse.org password, and their CAPTCHA image is terrible. I have a 1920x1080 screen, magnifying the image 200%, entering all the very fuzzy characters I could find ("Is that a 7, a slash, or nothing at all?"), and it keeps saying "The answer you entered for the CAPTCHA was not correct." I have tried between 20 and 30 times. There is no other way that I can see to get around this. I have used CAPTCHA on other sites without a problem.

Comment: Were you going to put a screenshot of the problem here?

Comment: I agree with you about their image quality. I changed my password earlier today and the first two CAPTCHA values I entered were rejected even though I was confident that they were correct. Also see Eclipse [**Bug 514660 reCAPTCHA not working for certain users**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514660): _"This CAPTCHA is extremely difficult and it took me several attempts"_!